# How does one stop elements from overlapping during and after a scaletransform animation in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, rendertransform

I have a ListBox that has items with a `RenderTransform` based on a `Style.Triggers` attribute with storyboard animation including a scaletransform of `x 1.5` and `y 1.5`. The result is hideous, and I am looking for a way to get the items to stop overlapping as they do in the image below.

[image: The horrible animation effect on the regions that the ListBoxItems occupy.]

Comment: Set the LayoutTransform property instead of RenderTransform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RenderTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) is applied after the layout is done - meaning that the sizes and positions of the UI elements are already computed. Applying the transform at this point won't move the surrounding elements.

Instead, you could set the transform to the [LayoutTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) property - then the transform will be applied during the layout pass.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I was using `RenderTransform.ScaleX` and `RenderTransform.ScaleY`. I changed these to `LayoutTransform.ScaleX` and `LayoutTransform.ScaleY`. This happened because `LayoutTransform` is applied before the layout takes place and `RenderTransform` occurs after the layout takes place.